# Angular 7 - deploy workspace applications (projects) in isolation

Tags: angular, webpack, deployment, chunks

In my cli-generated workspace I have the root-application which lazy loads numerous application (sitting in the projects folder).

When I run "ng build root-application", all the chunks are placed in the dist/root-application folder, and I could copy this folder across to my server, and we're good to go.

However, these applications are almost never at the same stage in their development life-cycle (still in development, some being QA'd), and I want to de able to deploy them in isolation, rather than having to deploy the whole site.

Does anyone have a strategy for this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok Doing All this work manually will be a cumbersome process, there are tools which can help automate this work. Nx (nrwl.io) can help you solve your problem, it uses a Monorepo approach where you can build multiple angular/react application/libraries in one workspace, all this application can be independent of each other. To get started [click here](https://nx.dev/getting-started/what-is-nx). To read about why to use Nx [click here](https://blog.nrwl.io/12-things-to-help-large-organizations-do-angular-right-f261a798ad6b). Nx has been designed by Victor Savkin (Core Angular Team Member who has designed lots of features for angular)

Comment: I can't emphasise enough just how good the Nx toolset is - anybody working on enterprise Angular projects should check it out. The affected:xxx scripts they provide are truly next-level from a devops perspective for managing complex multi app/library ecosystems.

Answer (score -1):

So, my solution in the end was the create libraries (ng generate library) instead of applications (ng generate application).
I could then individually publish my libraries to NPM.
I could then deploy my whole site, but by only upgrading the desired library in my package.json file, I was able to 'deploy' the desired part of the site in isolation.